# Positioning background image on form element with CSS sprites

Tags: html, css, markup, css-sprites, sprite

I am trying to get a magnifying glass as the background for my input element. The magnifying glass icon is part of a CSS sprite that looks like this:

[image]

To position it, I've used these properties:

```
#search-form input[type="text"] {
    background: url('../images/icons.png') no-repeat left center;
    background-position: 0px -30px;
    border: 1px solid #a9e2ff;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

But the background still appears at the top of the input box rather than aligned in the vertical middle and to the left. I've also tried doing:

`background: url('../images/icons.png') no-repeat left middle;`

but that doesn't work either.

If it matters, although I'm guessing it doesn't, here's my form markup:

```
<form action="/search" method="get" id="search-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="s">
</form>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You declared `background-position` two times. The first one at the end of the `background` short-hand property, the second one on the next line. **Solution**: Split all single `background` rules like this *(additionally, `0 -24px` is the correct value)*:

```
#search-form input[type="text"] {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFpLm.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 -24px;
    border: 1px solid #a9e2ff;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

And now you can face the real problem with your design: other sprites will be visible in the input area if there are no sufficient space between them.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there would be a way to do this without adding extra space between my sprites, but apparently not. :)

Comment: @MartinHoe Usually you just need to wrap the sprite in a box that is exactly big as the icon size. Unfortunaly you cannot do this, because you can't have block elements inside an input box.