# HTML5 Multiple Input on one background

Tags: html, css

Honestly speaking, is it possible to do with CSS3 and HTML5?

I'm trying to attach multiple input with properties of
`float:left`

But here's the challenging part i'm facing :-

[image]

Each time when the width and height changes, the input will go haywire.
Is it possible to fix the input at the centre of the image?

The output should be something below :
[image]

I've tried multiple various way, so now I'm using this table method :

HTML :

```
<section id="offer"> 
<table WIDTH="100%" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" BORDER="0">
<tr>
<td WIDTH="100%">
<div class="fixedimage">
<img src="Projects/Sojo/Documentation/Slice/01_Home/banner.png" />
      <input type="text" id="formElement">
</div>    
</td>
</tr>
</table>
  </section>
```

CSS:

```
#offer {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    clear: both;
    background-color: rgba(246,246,246,1.00);
    color: rgba(146,146,146,1.00);
    padding-top: 57px;
    padding-bottom: 57px;
}

.fixedimage img{
    width:100% !important;
    height:100%;
    display:block;    
}

#formElement
{
    position:absolute;
    top:600px;
    left:25px;
}
```

I'm using top and left on the form element for responsiveness. So when the width is less than 540px i'll overwrite the height and width.

My codepen IO : https://codepen.io/jayvicious/pen/bRGWyx

I'm open to critics and suggestion .
If there's better method than using the current table method, i'm all ears.

Comment: is there a reason why the background image is not a page background? And yes, there are always better options than using a table element

Comment: @Icepickle, i tried that method here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039883/positioning-background-image-on-form-element-with-css-sprites with modifying some codes. No luck when it comes to responsiveness .

Comment: @Icepickle, could you suggest me other method so i can google and get another idea of producing the result. thanks in advance

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: @LGSon, if possible chrome,safari and firefox.

Comment: Okay, asked because IE9 and lower does not support flexbox, but since you don't need to support those, you are good to go, but if you want to support them, let me know and I'll post a responsive alternative to absolute positioning

Comment: As Flexbox can be tricky with prefixed properties on older browsers, you might find this useful, using `display: table`, https://jsfiddle.net/vot15gdt/ ... it is simple and fully responsive compared to absolute positioning, and if you do, I can post this as an answer.

Comment: @LGSon, dude this is what exactly i'm looking for. As long it's not table width with fixed then it's cool with me. I just checked out the responsiveness it's quite good. Hit me up with the answer, I'll upvote for your effort and will tick it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Flexbox can be tricky with prefixed properties on older browsers, you might find this useful, using `display: table`

It is simple and fully responsive compared to absolute positioning.

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vot15gdt)

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#offer {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(246,246,246,1);
  color: rgba(146,146,146,1);
  background: url(http://www.hotelstanchini.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/tessera-1400x529.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.cell.at-bottom {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.cell div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3)
}
.cell div * {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section id="offer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <div>
        <h1>EXPERIENCE</h1>
        <h5>The moder home of Japan</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell at-bottom">
      <input type="text" class="formElement">
      <input type="text" class="formElement">
      <input type="text" class="formElement">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: LGSon, is it advisable to create another container within the offer div?
This is what i facing with my codepen : https://codepen.io/jayvicious/pen/gROxaV.
The form input is at the top center. So i assume, if creating a div class with a specific height and width can fix it? if responsiveness ill use media queries.

Comment: @FreedomPride You need to remove `position: absolute` from the `.formElement` rule

Comment: @FreedomPride And if the _offer_ should take full height, also the `#mainWrapper` need `height: 100%`

Comment: for a moment ago, i thought i had to use z-index if i'm emphasizing on absolute. It work great ! really appreciate your effort. Even the output for the responsiveness is like this: http://imgur.com/a/tGK0B
Ill try to use media queries to set the height , width of the offer and mainwrapper to 50% if the width is less than 540px

Comment: @FreedomPride Yes, media query will be needed to control wider/narrower screens. I also recommend to remove as many as possible of your `float` and `absolute`, since they often affect responsiveness to the lesser good

Comment: But if i want to make like for example, an image beside another image. I would put in a div id class in a specific width and height. then for the second image ill just put it float left. That's a good practice ? or no?

Comment: @FreedomPride I'm just saying, sometimes `float` is really needed, though don't make it your general solution for stacking elements side-by-side ... i.e. image that you mention, they are inline and will do that automatically

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) for that as it is a perfect choice when it comes to vertically center content, and combine that with [background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image?v=example) CSS property:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  min-height: 80vh;
  
  background: url('http://www.hotelstanchini.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/tessera-1400x529.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.search-form {
  display: flex;
  padding: 16px;
}

.search-form input {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
  <form class="search-form" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="All Japan Cities" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Check In Date" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Check Out Date" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="One Guest" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

You can read [more about flexbox here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: This is a new feature , i'm going to upvote it to check it and will feedback .

Comment: When it comes to `flexbox` remember that you must vendor-prefix some of the properties for the older browsers (for example with https://autoprefixer.github.io or another tool), but it allows for greater flexibility. For example, whenever you would like this form to be at the bottom, just change `align-items` to `flex-end` and it's there. No magic numbers and fully responsive!

Answer (score 1):

I hope to have understood your intent. The following is an alternative.

I changed the code, now the image has 50% width.

```css
/* reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul, ol {
  list-style: none;
}
/* styles */
.hero_wrap {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.hero_img {
  width: 50%;
}
.hero_over {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
}
.controls_list {
  text-align: center;
}
.hero_over li {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_wrap">
  <img class="hero_img" src="http://www.hotelstanchini.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/tessera-1400x529.jpg" />
  <div class="hero_over">
    <ul class="controls_list">
      <li><input type="text"></li>
      <li><input type="text"></li>
      <li><input type="text"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a new feature , i'm going to upvote for taking your time to write a solution and will feedback .

Comment: if i set the class hero wrap to width 100% is it possible cause , the background just cut by half :P

Comment: I changed the style.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Add following styles:

```
.fixedimage {
 position:relative;
 text-align:center;
 }

#formElement
{
position:absolute;
top:50%;
}
```

if you want to use position:absolute for your element (absolute positioning on parent element) you should define position:relative for it's parent.
for centering your element you need to add top:50%. also for horizontal centering you add text-align:center on parent element.

also you don't need Table elements.

Comment: This is a new feature , i'm going to upvote for taking your time to write a solution and will feedback .

Comment: Ill try to remove the table but this one will ruin the responsiveness?

Answer (score 1):

Try use this css code:

```
.fixedimage {
 position:relative;
}
#formElement{
position:absolute;
display:block;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:50% auto 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This is a new feature , i'm going to upvote for taking your time to write a solution and will feedback .

Comment: Somehow it's not working thou , i tried it on my codepen. The input box just disappear